# Is it fine to tag/retag questions on specific frameworks with a language tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

For example: a question is originally tagged "jsp servlets". Is it fine to retag it to "jsp servlets java". Same goes for the case when asking a question.

- this will allow more people who are watching the "java" tag to see it and eventually be helpful
- it will also mean that it will be "uninteresting" for others in the "java" tag who don't have experience with jsp or servlets.
- it might be considered 'polluting' the "java" tag with questions that are only indirectly related to java (by virtue of being written in java)

("java" above is just an example, same goes for every language)

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34547/auto-assign-language-tags-to-questions-based-on-other-tags

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36695/how-can-i-see-questions-about-java-no-i-mean-really-about-java

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant with "polluting" the java tag. But then, it seems there is some solution to that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope so, because I do this all the time.

I really can't see what the negatives of doing this are. Questions related to JSP and Servlets *are* Java questions.

Comment: As long as it is still tagged `jsp` too they can always remove it from search results at least.

Answer (score 7):

I'd say only do so if the question lies in your area of expertise and you're 100% sure the new tag applies.  I remember that there were differing opinions on whether every `c#` question also needed the `.net` tag.  Also, I'm tempted to add `java` to every question tagged `android` but I'm not certain it always applies, or if it always *will* apply in the future.

Comment: The part about the future annoy me too. I can't be sure and it'd be one hell of a retagging effort to fix it if it became false.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say that's probably fine, but more so because it's all part of the `java` development toolchain, rather than the java language specifically.

Answer (score 1):

You can end up running out of tag space.  If a question is tagged "`servlets jsp google-collections optimization`" and try to add all implied tags you have "`servlets jsp java google-collections guava optimization performance`" etc.  You can't because of the 5-tag limit, so you have to drop one.  Arguably "java" is the best tag to drop.

Answer (score 1):

There are some who really don't like this, because it confuses questions that really pertain to the language of java as opposed to the platform.  And they have a point.  But personally I think the need to tag for your platform supercedes that, and so I say go for it.

Comment: The solution to this is to have two different tags for the language and the platform if there actually is a need.