# Automatically add category tag(s) to questions, or at least suggest them

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-hierarchy

It seems [almost](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6514/tag-hierarchy-to-browse-through-tags) all requests to add tag category/hierarchy/organization/etc have been shot down.

I'm suggesting a different variety: automatically add the appropriate "category" tag(s) when the question is posted.

Here's an example for my personal interest, very similar to [a previous answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6514/tag-hierarchy-to-browse-through-tags/10935#10935): On SO there's `swing` tag, but many people (especially `n00b`s) use specific tags like `jtable`, `jlabel`, etc. without using the `swing` tag. It would be a huge pain, if not impossible, to add all `JComponent` subclasses to my interested tags and RSS feed.

Per [ThePony's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6514/tag-hierarchy-to-browse-through-tags/6516#6516), moderators would try to merge/retag, but it obviously hasn't happened (at least not completed) with those JComponent tags.

So instead of imposing it on our dearly-beloved mods, why not let the engine do it automatically, so that whenever a question with only `jtable` is posted, add `swing` to it? Or at least it can suggest the category tag(s) to the user.

The tag categorization/hierarchy should be maintained by mods or with high rep users on the category tag (the swing tag in my case).

Comment: Duplicate of [Could we make tags imply other tags?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2781) and even more of [Auto assign language tags to questions based on other tags.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34547). The problem I see is, "child" tags *don't* necessarily imply any relevance to their parent: plenty of jQuery questions aren't about JavaScript, plenty of C# questions aren't about the .NET libraries. This isn't a technical problem... See also: [On guidelines to tagging and avoiding unnecessary tags.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61307)

Comment: No and no. In my example, 1) `jtable` tag stays as is. It does *NOT* imply `swing`. Instead `swing` is automatically added (or at least suggested) to the question. 2) I did *NOT* suggest adding `java`. `swing` is a large and self-sufficient enough tag to stand on itself. Only St. Skeet can follow language tags.